# Why this Mojolicious websockets example does not work?

Tags: perl, websocket, mojolicious

I have tried some websockets simple examples to try them out, but no one works for me. Here is one example [A WebSocket Mojolicious/DBI Example](http://blogs.perl.org/users/joel_berger/2012/10/a-websocket-mojoliciousdbi-example.html)

I run it with plackup on port 5000 and everything should work fine. But when trying add some record i see on terminal just:

```
[Sat Mar  9 11:05:57 2013] [debug] GET /insert (Anonymojo).
[Sat Mar  9 11:05:57 2013] [debug] Template "not_found.development.html.ep" not found.
[Sat Mar  9 11:05:57 2013] [debug] Template "not_found.html.ep" not found.
[Sat Mar  9 11:05:57 2013] [debug] Rendering cached inline template.
[Sat Mar  9 11:05:57 2013] [debug] Rendering cached inline template.
[Sat Mar  9 11:05:57 2013] [debug] 404 Not Found (0.012583s, 79.472/s).
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Mar/2013:11:05:57 +0200] "GET /insert HTTP/1.1" 404 6440 "-" "-"
```

I get the almost same (exept UserAgent part) result when I target browser on "/insert".

In example script websockets route is defined but it gets never hit:

```
# setup websocket message handler
websocket '/insert' => sub {
```

So, what may be wrong here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Websockets (and the other real-time features too IIRC) only work with the Mojolicious servers: daemon, morbo and hypnotoad. Does your example work under say morbo?

Comment: To be exact, the example is yours ;) And, yes, it works under morbo, I was not aware about real-time bit. Thank you!

Comment: I've been surprised at how many comments I get from people about those posts! I should say, the database code is REALLY basic and probably wont work in a preforking (hypnotoad) environment correctly. I should probably go back and update them. Still they are good for an introduction, which is what they are. Good luck!